# Are all particles in the universe quantum-entangled on some level?

Tags: cosmology, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement, cosmic-microwave-background

The CMB indicates the universe was in a thermal equilibrium early on, which I understand indicates causal connection. There appears to have been some rapid expansion, and the universe now appears to have parts that will always be out of causal contact from now on (as far as we can tell). Since entanglement is transferred, none of the "information" is lost just transferred during interactions.

Now if one measures the spin of a random free fermion to be spin up say, then I'm thinking the spin of all other fermions in the universe has an infinitesimally lower probability of being found to be spin up.

Such that if you could measure half the spins in the particles in the universe as up, you could be certain the other half would be measured to be spin down.
This of course assumes a zero net spin for the universe. Is this line of thinking correct?

Comment: Why don't you try assuming, say, a universe with four particles, specifying a typical state, specifying a family of measurements, and calculating what happens to see if it squares with your guesses?

Comment: Entanglement is not transferred in all interactions, this is the [measurement problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_problem). If it was, the universe would be (and would always have been) described by a single wavefunction. But described by who I don't know, since then we would not exist as classical creatures in a classical world.

Comment: Related: [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.1584). Its conclusion is: "The cosmological quantum state is likely to be typical in a Hilbert space describing degrees of freedom over a region many times as large as the visible universe (our current horizon volume). This implies a high degree of entanglement of particles, with the entanglement distributed uniformly over most of the degrees of freedom. As a consequence, small subsystems are mostly entangled with particles far beyond the horizon, and two randomly chosen small subsystems are unlikely to be directly entangled with each other."

Comment: The paper linked in the above comment only deals with unitary evolution, so the points made in my first comment still apply IMO. The analysis also neglects relativistic considerations (only using the notion of horizon), which makes sense since we do not have a theory of quantum gravity yet, but also means that its discussion of the question is based on shaky foundations, IMO again.

Comment: The [similar question in Quora](http://www.quora.com/Are-all-particles-in-the-universe-quantum-entangled-since-they-all-emerged-from-a-single-entity) has some interesting answers.